# c fork pipe and read fucntion gives random bytes from file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

hi I'm having some problems with my c program. The goal is to `fork` twice and then pass some data with `pipe` from child two to child one and then some different data from child one to parent and finally print it out in parent. Here is my code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int f,f2,nread;
    int pfd[2], pfd2[2];
    char buffer[512], *str;

    if(pipe(pfd)==-1) {
        errorHandler("pipe");
    }

    if((f=fork())==-1) {
        errorHandler("fork 1");
    } else if(f == 0) {
        /*child 1*/
        if(pipe(pfd2)==-1) {
            errorHandler("pipe 2");
        }
        if((f2=fork())==-1) {
            errorHandler("fork 2");
        } else if(f2 == 0) {
            /*child 2*/
            close(pfd[0]);
            close(pfd[1]);
            close(pfd2[0]);
            str = "rollin";
            printf("-child 2 writing: %s\n", str);
            if(write(pfd2[1], &str, BUFFSIZE)==-1) {
                errorHandler("write 2");
            }
        } else {
            /*child 1*/
            close(pfd[0]);
            close(pfd2[1]);
            if((nread=read(pfd2[0], &buffer, 512))==-1) {
                errorHandler("read child 1");
            }

            buffer[nread] = 0;
            printf("child 1 read data %d [%s]\n", nread, buffer);

            str = "patrollin patrolling hehe";
            printf("-child 1 writing %s\n", str);
            if(write(pfd[1], &str, BUFFSIZE)==-1) {
                errorHandler("write");
            }
        }
    } else {
        /*parent*/
        close(pfd[1]);
        if((nread=read(pfd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer)))==-1) {
            errorHandler("read");
        } else {
            buffer[nread] = 0;
            printf("parent read data: %d [%s]\n", nread, buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is that the data is read(512 bytes as I specified) but it is not what i sent. I take some random signs from the memory instead(file descriptors are passeed properly, right?).
The reason I came here is I cannot figure out what is wrong with this. I have a program with only one fork and similar action and it's based on the same techniques and it is working. Can anyone give me a hint what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `read` is a pointer to the buffer. The second argument to `write` is a pointer to the data to write. So you should use

```
read(pfd2[0], buffer, 512)
```

and

```
write(pfd2[1], str, BUFFSIZE)
```